# Insert multiple rows with hardcoded data, and one column from a multi-result select

Tags: sql, oracle, select, insert-into

I have the following two tables: `Users` and `Settings`.
What I want to do is add a row to the settings for each existing User. So in pseudo-code:

```
foreach(NUMBER user_id IN Users){
  INSERT INTO "Settings" SET ("name", "value", "type", type_id, overridable)
                       VALUES ('date_format', 'dd-MM-yyyy', 'USER', user_id, '1');
}
```

How do I do this in SQL?

[Here at the *Using INSERT with the VALUE Clause and a SELECT Subquery* part](https://technet.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/ms188263(v=sql.105).aspx) I see the following:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (PriKey, Description)
   SELECT ForeignKey, Description
   FROM SomeView;
```

which is almost what I want to accomplish, except that it gets all it's insert-values from the other table, instead of only one (`user_id` in my case) with the others 'hard-coded'.

EDIT: I'm using SQL with an Oracle database.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Added it: SQL with Oracle DB.

Comment: Unrelated, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I completely agree, but unfortunately someone else made the DB and I and some others in my team have to work with it.. If it were up to me I would have picked other DB-columns that aren't SQL keywords.. I'll discuss this with the team and see if we should change it now or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `select .. insert` and provide the constants in the select list:

```
INSERT INTO "Settings" ("name", "value", "type", type_id, overridable)
select 'date_format', 'dd-MM-yyyy', 'USER', user_id, '1'
from users;
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Was a lot easier than I thought. I'll accept your answer in 10 minutes.